# Naming a new file with timestamp?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a simple command line program that lets me keep track of how many times I get distracted during a study session.

I'm getting an argument error when I run this code saying my `file.open` has invalid arguments. If I want to name each `new_session` file with a timestamp, what would be a simple solution?

```
def first_question
    puts "Would you like to start a new session?"
    answer = gets.chomp
    answer = answer.downcase

    if answer == "yes"
        new_session
    else
        puts "Ok. Would you like to review a previous session?"
        prev_session = gets.chomp
        prev_session.downcase
        if prev_session == "yes"
            #GET AND REVIEW PREVIOUS SESSIONS
        elsif prev_session == "no"
            puts "Well if you don't want a new session, and you don't want to review your old sessions, then you're SOL."
        else
            "That's not an acceptable response."
            first_question
        end
    end
end

def new_session
    distractions = 0
    d = File.open("Session"+Time.now.to_s , 'w'){|f| f.write(distractions) }


    puts "What would you like to do (add track(s) or review tracks)?"
    request = gets.chomp
    request.downcase    
    if request == "add track"
        distractions = distractions.to_i + 1
        puts "You have #{distractions} tracks in this session."
    elsif request == "add tracks"
        puts "How many times have you been distracted since we last met?"
        answer = gets.chomp
        distractions = distractions.to_i + answer.to_i
        puts "You have #{distractions} tracks."
    elsif request == "review tracks"
        puts distractions
    end
    File.open( d , 'w') {|f| f.write(distractions) }
end

first_question
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why this deserves downvotes while the answer that doesn't even answer the question gets an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

Most of your code is messy and redundant. The problem you are referring to, though, comes from here:

```
d = File.open("Session"+Time.now.to_s , 'w'){|f| f.write(distractions) }
```

`d` will be the number of bytes written to the file and thus a Fixnum. You can't open a Fixnum which you're trying to do in the last line of the function.

Further,

```
request = gets.chomp
request.downcase
```

The second line here does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `File.open` statements:

```
d = File.open("Session"+Time.now.to_s , 'w'){|f| f.write(distractions) }
```

and:

```
File.open( d , 'w') {|f| f.write(distractions) }
```

Your error code will tell you which one is wrong, but, from looking at them, I'd say it's the second one.

`d` will be assigned the result of the block for the first `File.open`, which is going to be the result of `f.write(distractions)`:

The [`File.open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open) docs say:

> The value of the block will be returned from File.open.

The [`File.write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-write) docs say:

> Returns the number of bytes written.

As a result, you are assigning `d` a number of bytes, then trying to create a file with an integer for a filename, which is an error because a filename *MUST* be a string.

That leads to a bigger problem, which is, your code makes no sense.

- `d = File.open("Session"+Time.now.to_s , 'w'){|f| f.write(distractions) }` writes a `0` to the file created by `"Session"+Time.now.to_s`.
- `request.downcase` converts the contents of `request` to lowercase and immediately throws it away. Perhaps you meant `request.downcase!`, but it'd be better to write:

  ```
  request = gets.chomp
  request.downcase
  ```

  As:

  ```
  request = gets.chomp.downcase
  ```
- `distractions = distractions.to_i + 1`? `distractions` is already `0` which is a Fixnum. You're converting a Fixnum to an integer using `to_i` then adding 1 to it. Simply do:

  ```
  distractions += 1
  ```
- `distractions = distractions.to_i + answer.to_i` should be:

  ```
  distractions += answer.to_i
  ```
- `File.open( d , 'w') {|f| f.write(distractions) }`, because it's *trying* to write to a file with the integer name, won't update your original file. If it succeeded, it'd write to an entirely new file, which would end up overwriting the previously created file, which was the result of writing a single `0` to disk. Instead, `d` should be the name of the file previously created.

Consider this:

```
def new_session

  distractions = 0

  puts "What would you like to do (add track(s) or review tracks)?"
  request = gets.chomp.downcase

  case request
  when "add track"
    distractions += 1
    puts "You have #{distractions} tracks in this session."

  when "add tracks"
    puts "How many times have you been distracted since we last met?"
    distractions += gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "You have #{distractions} tracks."

  when "review tracks"
    puts distractions
  end

  File.write( "Session" + Time.now.to_s, distractions) 
end
```

This code is cleaner, and makes more sense now.

Comment: Sorry for the bad code, I'm pretty new to this. I tried implementing your improved method but I'm still getting an invalid argument error upon running the code. `errno::EINVAL`